# Linking Mist pass to OutputFile Node Image cannot be performed using Python API?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, compositing-nodes

When attempting to link the mist pass output of a `Render Layer` node to the input image content of an `Output File` node, I found that no matter how I tried to connect the mist pass output, nothing would attach to it via the Python API. Manually, through the Blender GUI I could link the two fine, and get results as expected. The code to generate these nodes is as follows:

```
## Link shaders
tl = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.links

# Link raw image render layer to switch
tl.new(n_image_rl.outputs[0], n_switch.inputs[0])
# Link depth from raw image to depth file output
tl.new(n_image_rl.outputs[3], n_depth_out.inputs[0])
# Link image segment render layer
tl.new(n_img_seg_rl.outputs[0], n_alpha.inputs[1])
# Link field segment render layer
tl.new(n_field_seg_rl.outputs[0], n_col_key.inputs[0])
# Link color key node
tl.new(n_col_key.outputs[0], n_mix.inputs[1])
tl.new(n_col_key.outputs[1], n_mix.inputs[0])
# Link mix to alpha
tl.new(n_mix.outputs[0], n_alpha.inputs[2])
# Link alpha to switch
tl.new(n_alpha.outputs[0], n_switch.inputs[1])
# Link switch to composite output
tl.new(n_switch.outputs[0], n_comp.inputs[0])
```

This is the node linking received when the script was run, from within the `Compositing Nodes` window:

[image: Incorrect node listing for Python script.]

Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird. Might be a bug. It does not work with the output specified by it's index, but if I name the output, it works correctly. Try using:

```
tl.new(n_image_rl.outputs['Mist'], n_depth_out.inputs[0])
```